# contar el número de veces que aparece un elemento repetido en una lista en python

Tags: python, string, repetidos

Tengo el siguiente código para contar cuantas veces un elemento de una lista se repite

```
lista = [1,2,3,1,2]

repeticiones = {}

for n in lista:
      if n in repeticiones :
        repeticiones[n] += 1
      else:
         repeticiones[n] = 0

print(repeticiones)

print(len(repeticiones))
```

estos son los datos de la lista de entrada y sus salidas:

```
[1,2,3,1,2]   salida = 2
[1,1,1,1,1]   salida = 4
```

**"No debo usar importaciones para este ejercicio"**

Comment: Igual que te comenta @PatricioMoracho, solo te falta añadir a tu código algo para separar los que se repiten `repeticiones = {x:y for x, y in repeticiones.items() if y }`

Answer (score 2):

Una opción fácil y sencilla sin módulos  extra es usando la función `map()` y luego utilizar `zip` para combinar los valores para posteriormente pasarlo a un diccionario

```py
lista = [1,2,3,1,2]
dict(zip(lista,map(lambda x: lista.count(x),lista)))
```

Utilizamos `map()` y le aplicamos una lambda esta lambda obtendrá la veces que se repite un valor, esto para cada valer de la lista. Luego se utiliza `zip()` para *mezclar* ambos datos y obtener una tapa para posteriormente pasarlo a un diccionario.
**resultado**

```
{1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mira espero te funcione este codigo; use la libreria de *collections* en especifico **Counter**, que se usa para contar los elementos de una lista.

```
from collections import Counter
lista = [1,2,3,1,2]
conteo=Counter(lista)

resultado={}
for clave in conteo:  
   valor=conteo[clave]
    if valor != 1:
    resultado[clave] = valor
print(resultado)
```

El resultado sería:`{1: 2, 2: 2}`

Ahora bien, si dices que sin importar librerias sería así:

```
lista = [1,2,3,1,2]

repeticiones = {}
for n in lista:
  if n in repeticiones :
    repeticiones[n] += 1
  else:
    repeticiones[n] = 0

print(repeticiones)
print(len(repeticiones))

resultado={}
for clave in repeticiones:  
  valor=repeticiones[clave]
  if valor != 0:
    resultado[clave] = valor
print(resultado)
print(len(resultado))
```

El resultado sería:`{1: 1, 2: 1}`

Comment: Es una muy buena opción, pero el OP solo quiere el elemento que más se repite, y no detalla como sería en el caso que varios coincidan, pero nice

Comment: Gracias @LuthienBtz en este ejercicio no debo usar importaciones, como se podria resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Tu código está correcto, pero te dice la cantidad de ocurrencias de cada elemento. Aplicando [count()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) en vez de un acumulador manual:

```
ocurrencias = dict((i, lista.count(i)) for i in lista)
# {1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1}
```

La cantidad de repeticiones debe ser la cantidad de ocurrencias - 1

```
repeticiones = {}
for i in lista:
    if lista.count(i) > 1:
        repeticiones[i] = lista.count(i) - 1
```

O lo que es lo mismo, escrito en forma *comprehensiva*:

```
repeticiones = dict((i, lista.count(i)-1) for i in lista if lista.count(i)>1)
# {1: 1, 2: 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

El metodo count puede ser tu mejor aliado, sino se te permite usar funciones predefinidas podrias reescribirla.
Lo normal seria contar cuantas veces el elemento esta en la lista, pero lo que buscas hacer es contar cuantas veces se repite. Lo que es un valor menos.
Halle la solucion con un if lista.count(n) != 1: que verifica si el elemento solo aparece una vez.

```
lista = [1,2,3,1,2]
repeticiones = {}

for n in lista:
    if lista.count(n) != 1:
        if n in repeticiones :
            repeticiones[n] += 1
        else:
            repeticiones[n] = 0
print(repeticiones)
```

Comment: tengo un dato de entrada de lista [1,1,1,1,1] pero la salida me bota 1 y deberia botar 4, como lo ajusto ?

Answer (score 1):

Mas allá que hay formas más "pythonicas" de resolver el problema, lo cierto es que tu código resuelve bien la primer parte, encontrar las repeticiones, lo único que tendrías que agregar es un filtro, para que solo te muestren aquellos elementos del diccionario `repeticiones` que tenga al menos 1 repetición. La forma más simple es usar una comprensión de listas:

```
repeticiones = {k:v for k, v in repeticiones.items() if v > 0}
```

El resultado es un diccionario similar al original pero únicamente con aquellos elementos con una o más repetición.

Comment: @pmoracho gracias, intento correr el programa con una linea de entrada de [1,1,1,1,1] y me imprime 1 en vez de 4 como podría solucionarlo ?

Comment: @oscarperez, no puedo reproducir ese comportamiento, con el código de tu pregunta más lo que te respondí, obtengo `{1: 3}` , por cierto, nunca te va a dar 4, por que inicializas en 0.

Comment: @pmoracho en ese resultado {1: 3} como hago para imprimir solo ese 3 ?

Comment: @oscarperez la respuesta puntual a tu comentario podría ser `repeticiones [1]` pero esto solo funciona cuando la clave es 1,  ¿tienes claro lo que es un diccionario en python?